how to trigger class equivalence inference in Protege based on properties
I want Protégé to infer that a certain class (or individual) is equivalent to another class if it has specific properties.
The following is a minimal snippet showing the issue. I expect the reasoner to figure out that VaccinesCauseAutism is a type of MedicalConspiracyTheory.
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

:involves rdf:type rdf:ObjectProperty . 
:Medicine rdf:type owl:Class .
:SecretPlan rdf:type owl:Class .

:MedicalConspiracyTheory a owl:Class ;
  rdfs:label "Medical Conspiracy Theory" ;
  owl:equivalentClass [ 
    rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty :involves ;
    owl:someValuesFrom [
      rdf:type owl:Class ;
      owl:intersectionOf ( :SecretPlan :Medicine )
    ]
  ] .

:VaccinesCauseAutism a owl:Class;
  rdfs:label "Vaccines Cause Autism" ;
  :involves :SecretPlan, :Medicine .

What am I doing wrong here?

The original was not working because the reasoner could not handle the objects of the :involves property being classes. it would only work with instances.
the following code works - I create two anonymous instances of the :SecretPlan and :Medicine classes, and that appears to do the trick.
I also had to rewrite the equivalentClass code, but I don't know why - as far as I can tell the new version does basically the same as the old, but the old version does not work. If someone can follow up with an explanation for that, I would be very thankful.
This version of the code works fine:
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

:involves rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .
:Medicine rdf:type owl:Class .
:SecretPlan rdf:type owl:Class .

:MedicalConspiracyTheory rdf:type owl:Class ;
  rdfs:label "Medical Conspiracy Theory" ;
  owl:equivalentClass [
    owl:intersectionOf (
      [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
        owl:onProperty :involves ;              
        owl:someValuesFrom :Medicine
      ]                                  
      [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
        owl:onProperty :involves ;
        owl:someValuesFrom :SecretPlan
      ]                                               
    ) ;                                        
    rdf:type owl:Class                  
  ] .                                

:VaccinesCauseAutism rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual;
  :involves 
    [rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual,:Medicine ],
    [rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual,:SecretPlan ];
  rdfs:label "Vaccines Cause Autism" .


The reason that the new equivalentClass code works is because it's checking an intersection of two restrictions - that :involves has an entry which is a Medicine and that :involves has an entry which is a SecretPlan.
The original equivalentClass was checking that there was at least one element associated  via :involves which was both a SecretPlan and a Medicine as far as I can tell.

the issue here is that in your first try you were using something dubbed "punning" with the statements :VaccinesCauseAutism :involves :SecretPlan, :Medicine . - those statements being asserted on a class make all three entities being used here being individuals. On the other hand, in your restriction owl:intersectionOf ( :SecretPlan :Medicine ) you are talking about classes.

Even while using the same URI, there is a difference for the class :SecretPlan and the individual :SecretPlan when doing reasoning. Especially, the individual :SecretPlan is not an instance of the class :SecretPlan

the other issue was that there is a fundamental difference in the semantics between saying MedicalConspiracyTheory EquivalentTo (involves some (SecretPlan and Medicine ) which you did before (and sounds wrong to be and wasn't the intended meaning) and MedicalConspiracyTheory EquivalentTo (involves some SecretPlan)  and  (involves some Medicine )
